# How to solve ˜The getter 'documentID' was called on null.˜?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, scoped-model

I have this function with scoped model in which I want to have a firebase increment to snapshot when the button is pressed, but It returns ˜The getter 'documentID' was called on null.˜, it changes the state of my icon but the number is not incremented. If I give the name of the document it works fine, but I don't want to specify it. Any thoughts on what could be the solution?

```
void main() {
runApp(EaiCasimiro());
}



class EaiCasimiro extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ScopedModel<LikesModel>(
    model: LikesModel(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: "E aí,  Casimiro?",
      home: HomeScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      )
    );
   }
}


class LikesModel extends Model {

DocumentSnapshot snapshot;




bool _liked = true;

static LikesModel of(BuildContext context) =>
  ScopedModel.of<LikesModel>(context, rebuildOnChange: true);


bool isLiked() => _liked;




void pressed(){
_liked = !_liked;
notifyListeners();
 }

void changeLikes() {
Firestore.instance
    .collection("lanchonetes")
    .document(snapshot.documentID)
    .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(_liked ? -1 : 1)});


    }

}
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code well in your question so it's easier to read.  It seems you've lost a lot of indentation, and that makes it difficult. You can mark whole blocks of text as code by simply starting and end the entire block with three backticks: ```

Comment: Thanks for your tip Doug, I`ll try to make it better next time I post a code.

Comment: You can always go back and edit the code right now by clicking the "edit" link at the bottom of the question and making changes in the editor.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a lot of code here, but haven't noted a specific line where the error occurs, I'll guess it happens here:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("lanchonetes")
    .document(snapshot.documentID)
    .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(_liked ? -1 : 1)});
```

It took me a while to find where you defined `snapshot`, but I found it here:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
```

Since you didn't assign a value when you declared it, it's going to have an initial value of null.  So, when you use it in the query like this: `snapshot.documentID`, you're getting that error.

Make sure `snapshot` is defined before you use it.

Comment: Do you know how I can define it? I tried different ways, searched a lot, but the closest I got was with a .forEach, but it incremented all my documents.